# Issue when disabling a path using PATH Manager

Tags: windows-7, path

I'd like to use [PATH Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pathmanager/) to disable/enable a given path from the PATH environment variable in a convenient way.

I am trying to disable the path `C:\programming\python\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.3\python-2.7.9`, so I unchecked the corresponding "Active" and the "System" boxes, then hit the save button:

[image]

I then started a new cmd.exe window, but I [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4002828/395857) that `C:\programming\python\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.3\python-2.7.9` is still in the path:

[image]

I checked the user's and system's PATH variables, they don't contain  `C:\programming\python\WinPython-32bit-2.7.9.3\python-2.7.9` anymore.

Did I miss something?

Comment: I assume you restarted your system before you checked?

Comment: @Ramhound When I edit the path using the small and inconvenient Windows edit box I just need to start a new cmd.exe. Why would I need to restart my system in this case? (though it might do the trick indeed, but I have a bunch of computation running so I can't restart soon)

Comment: Well before you say it didn't work you have to try.

Comment: @Ramhound When I edit the path using the small and inconvenient Windows edit box I just need to start a new cmd.exe for path changes to be taken into account. In this case starting a new cmd.exe does not seem to work, hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked the source code. The program just edits the registry key which holds the `PATH` information ->  `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\path`

I did not see any command for telling the operating system that the key changed. So it seems that indeed a reboot is intended to be required. An option might be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189652/using-rundll32-user32-dll-to-indicate-that-a-users-environment-has-changed

Another problem: When clicking an `active` checkbox changes are not saved. And the save button stays disabled.

Summary: What does work:

1. Click `active` checkbox (this is what you actually want)
2. Add any new path (now save button is enabled)
3. Click save (now changing are stored in registry)
4. Open PowerShell window
5. Type `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("dummy","anyValue","User")` ( The last value can be `Machine`, `User` or `Process`. this  sends an update environment broadcast to the system)
6. Open new cmd and type `echo %path%` (or use `where`) (now changes from 1. are visible)

So, using `PATH Manager` is not comfortable at all. However, you could use a PowerShell script for editing `PATH` and immediately apply changes --> http://poshcode.org/3537